# Changing format of mongoDB aggregation result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Currently I am running this query to calculate averages and to return the data in a specific format:

```
db.metrics.aggregate([  
   {  
      $unwind:"$data"
   },
   {  
      $group:{  
         _id:"$data.configName",
         avg:{  
            $avg:"$data.linesCount"
         },
         data:{  
            $last:"$data"
         },
         date:{  
            $last:"$date"
         }
      }
   }
]).pretty()
```

On a collection which contains objects in this format:

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "date" : 1526569274000,
        }
        "date" : "20150220",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "configName" : "aaa",
                        "linesCount" : 500,
                        "insertedLinesCount" : 658,
                }
        ],
        "applicationName" : "loader"
}
```

Which returns this result:

```
{
        "_id" : "aaa",
        "avg" : 500,
        "data" : {
                "configName" : "aaa",
                "linesCount" : 500,
                "insertedLinesCount" : 658,
                "succeeded" : true
        },
        "date" : "20150220"
}
```

The details are correct but I'd like to change the format. Is there any way to take what is in the data object and return it so that the final result is a list of 1-1 mappings, like so:

```
{
        "_id" : "aaa",
        "avg" : 500,
        "configName" : "aaa",
        "linesCount" : 500,
        "insertedLinesCount" : 658,
        "fileFormat" : "",
        "date" : "20150220"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `$project` stage at the end of the result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$data.configName",
      avg: {
        $avg: "$data.linesCount"
      },
      data: {
        $last: "$data"
      },
      date: {
        $last: "$date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      configName: "$data.configName",
      insertedLinesCount: "$data.insertedLinesCount",
      linesCount: "$data.linesCount",
      succeeded: "$data.succeeded",
      _id: 1,
      avg: 1,
      date: 1
    }
  }
])
```

above query gives you the following result... check it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rz5J6FuqHov)

```
[
  {
    "_id": "aaa",
    "avg": 500,
    "configName": "aaa",
    "date": "20150220",
    "insertedLinesCount": 658,
    "linesCount": 500,
    "succeeded": true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `$replaceRoot` stage after `$group`

```
{
  $replaceRoot: {
     newRoot: {
        _id: "$_id",
        avg: "$avg",
        configName: "$data.configName"
        ...
     }
  }
}
```